# runAction module in console Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i have in console\controllers

```
    class TestController extends Controller
{


    public function actionTest()
    {
        Yii::$app->runAction('how?');

    }

}
```

and

```
backend\modules\mytestmodule\controllers\MyTestControllers

    public function actionCreate()
    {

        echo 1;

    }
```

Is it possible to call runAction "actionCreate" in console "actionTest" ?
 Yii::$app->runAction('/backend/modules/mytestmodule/MyTest/actionCreate');
dont work

console config

```
return [
'id' => 'console',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
'controllerMap' => [
    'command-bus' => [
        'class' => 'trntv\bus\console\BackgroundBusController',
    ],
    'message' => [
        'class' => 'console\controllers\ExtendedMessageController'
    ],
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
        'migrationPath' => '@common/migrations/db',
        'migrationTable' => '{{%system_db_migration}}'
    ],
    'rbac-migrate' => [
        'class' => 'console\controllers\RbacMigrateController',
        'migrationPath' => '@common/migrations/rbac/',
        'migrationTable' => '{{%system_rbac_migration}}',
        'templateFile' => '@common/rbac/views/migration.php'
    ],
],
```

];

Comment: You want to run this action  from console or from web app?

Comment: I need to run the actionCreate from the console in some way

Comment: Can you post your config console?

Comment: added to post config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found a solution but remember that the structure you desired isn't a good solution. Becouse you try to use `\Yii::$app->runAction()` in a console context so your `\Yii::$app` is an istance of `ConsoleApplication` and not `WebApplication` and the actions you can use in this context is different from the Web context.
But you can call a web context action in a console context with this workaround but i repeat that isn't a good idea for futher issue will be present:

```
use backend\modules\mytestmodule\controllers\MyTestController;

class TestController extends Controller
{


    public function actionTest()
    {
        //Yii::$app->runAction('how?'); you cannot use here run action for access an action in web context
        $controller = new MyTestController('mytest', $this->module);
        $controller->actionCreate();
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked for me. I'm now able to call a web action from a console action that is triggered by a cron job. Thanks. But I still not 100% sure why it's working. What are those parameters of the new controller "mytest" and especially "$this->module"?

Comment: Look at the constructor of Controller in Yii2: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#__construct()-detail

Answer (score 1):

It's very rare task for Yii2, but you may use this as an example:

```
// Here we call @frontend/site/index from @console/controller.
\Yii::$app->controllerNamespace = 'frontend\controllers'; //change current controller
\Yii::$app->runAction('site/index'); //run the Action
```

But, you may have an error about CSRF, cause App's controller (yii\webcontroller) is not the same as Console's controller (yii\console\controller)!

ps. if you don't change controller's namespace, runAction won't find desired Action.